# How to call ng-repeat sort by predicate code from Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have 2 directives, 1 controls the view for a list of tags and contains a couple of sort buttons and the other a popover menu with the same options:

[image]

Markup for **tagPanel**:

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="{'active':vol}"
            ng-click="vol = true; predicate = 'week_quantity'; reverse=!reverse">Vol</li>
        <li ng-class="{'active':!vol}"
            ng-click="vol = false; predicate = 'previous_day_quantity'; reverse=!reverse">Trend</li>
        <li><div class="quick-filter-ico" ng-click="toggleTagPopover()"></div></li>
        <li><div class="quick-search-ico"></div></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(k, m) in tags | orderBy:predicate:reverse"
            ng-class="{'selected': m.selected}"
            ng-click="selectTag(m)">
            <div class="tag">{{m.term}}</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Here are the isolated sorts:

```
<li ng-class="{'active':vol}"
    ng-click="vol = true;
    predicate = 'week_quantity'; reverse=!reverse">Vol</li>

<li ng-class="{'active':!vol}"
    ng-click="vol = false;
    predicate = 'previous_day_quantity'; reverse=!reverse">Trend</li>
```

Code in tagsPanel controller:

```
var vs = $scope;
ApiFactory.getTags(ticker).then(function(data) {

    // The tags model is set here:
    vs.tags = TagFactory.renderTags(ticker, data);
```

---

Now my goal is to toggle/activate the predicate code from another Directive controller **tagsPopover**.

This is code from tagsPopover:

```
var vs = $scope;

vs.toggleTags = function(type) {
    console.log(type);
    vs.tagsSort = {};

    switch(type) {
        case 'vol':
            vs.tagsSort.vol = true;
            // Here I need to call a function in tagsPanel
            // that will toggle the predicate code
            break;

        case 'trending':
            vs.tagsSort.trending = true;
            // Here I need to call a function in tagsPanel
            // that will toggle the predicate code
            break;
    }

    vs.tagsPopoverDisplay = false;
};
```

---

So my question is, how would you toggle the predicate code from the markup inside of a Directive / Controller?

```
predicate = 'previous_day_quantity'; reverse=!reverse
```

*Example of the type of function I will call inside of* **tagsPanel**:

```
vs.togglePredicate = function() {
    predicate = 'previous_day_quantity';
    reverse = !reverse;
};
```

Comment: Ah sec, it was as simple as I thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is exactly like the markup, just need to use my `$scope` variable to attach to it:

**tagsPopover**:

```
vs.toggleTags = function(type) {
    vs.tagsSort = {};
    tagsPanel   = ScopeFactory.getScope('tagsPanel'); 

    switch(type) {
        case 'all':
            vs.tagsSort.all = true;
            tagsPanel.togglePredicate('vol');
            break;

        case 'trending':
            vs.tagsSort.trending = true;
            tagsPanel.togglePredicate('trending');
            break;
    }

    vs.tagsPopoverDisplay = false;
};
```

Then in **tagsPanel**:

```
vs.togglePredicate = function(type) {

    console.log('togglePredicate called...');
    console.log(type);

    switch(type) {
        case 'vol':
            vs.predicate = 'week_quantity';
            vs.reverse   = !vs.reverse;
            break;

        case 'trending':
            vs.predicate = 'previous_day_quantity';
            vs.reverse   = !vs.reverse;

            console.log(vs.predicate);
            break;
    }
};
```